# widget radio not working in one2many line odoo

Tags: tree, treeview, odoo, odoo-12, one2many

Need to add widget radio to a field in one2many line in Odoo 12 community,
My code

```
<page string="Questions">
    <field name="evaluation_line_ids">
        <tree editable="bottom">
            <field name="training_id" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="ranking" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>
```

It shows the same as the selection field in Odoo, not as a radio button

Comment: A similar selection field with three items works fine in a one2many field list with the horizontal option set to true without any modifications to the web module.

Comment: @Kenly not working this code <field name="ranking" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>

Comment: I made a test on a clean Odoo 12 version. Check for code overriding the `radio` widget.